# Stubbing in multiple levels

Tags: java, mockito

I'm using mockito for stubbing.

This is a minimal representation of my setup. Assume getters and setters are in place

```
class Person {
   String name;
}

class Car {
   Person owner;
}

class CarPool {
   Car car;

   String getOwner() {
      car.getOwner.getName()
   }
}

class testClass {
  CarPool carPool = new CarPool();

  Car car = mock(Car.class);
  when(car.getOwner.getName()).thenReturn("name");

  carPool.setCar(car);

  assertEquals(carPool.getOwner, "name");
}
```

I get a nullpointer when trying this as the getOwner is not allready stubbed. Is it possible to do a stubbing like this? if not, what is the best solution in this case?

Comment: How come Mockito will know what to return on `carPool.getOwner`?

Comment: Theroretically it seams to me that Mockto knows the type of owner. So it could instasiate a mocked Owner object with a stubbed getName method

Comment: I mean what value? I dont think it will be so smart to do it on its own

Comment: I guess if it was possible it would be built in to the Mockito framework. What is the best way to do what I'm tring to do?

Comment: There is something like that built into Mockito, yes, but it's probably clearer if you EITHER just mock the owner explicitly, OR make a real `Person` object to use.

Comment: Ok, but if I mock the owner I also have to mock the person and som whens for that. This results in alot of code cluttering up the test. And it takes longer time writing. What is the thing that is built into Mockito?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do deep stubbing.

```
Car car = mock(Car.class, Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
```

Note that deep stubbing usually means that the code is not clean. Consider the following quote from the documentation:

> Every time a mock returns a mock a fairy dies.

Source: [Mockito documentation](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)

Comment: Just what I asked for, but I will absolutly read up on the law of demeter and why I should not use this